# angular chekcbox is checked change other input value

Tags: angular, checkbox

I want to find a solution that if I check a checkbox then the value of the input field in another div will change to disabled.

``

```
<div class="24hr-example">
        <input placeholder="24hr format" aria-label="24hr format" [ngxTimepicker]="fullTime" [format]="24"  readonly>
        <ngx-material-timepicker #fullTime></ngx-material-timepicker>
   </div>
```

``

`<app-checkbox [checked]="openingHours.is_closed_all_day" (change)="openingHours.is_closed_all_day = !openingHours.is_closed_all_day"></app-checkbox>`

So if I click on the checkbox then the value of the input field given will be taken as disabled. I've tried to solve it with a function, but it couldn't work. What solution is possible to solve this?

Comment: Try assigning disabled attribute to input like, ```<input placeholder="24hr format" aria-label="24hr format" [disabled]="openingHours.is_closed_all_day" ...```

Comment: Thank you @ManirajMurugan That solved my problem. :)

Comment: Then why you accept the solution provided below?? Does that also solve your issue??

Comment: Whats your problem? @ManirajMurugan

Comment: I don't have any problem Mr.. You mentioned that my solution solved your issue.. Then you also accepted the answer below.. So asked whether that also solve your problem.. I have asked to post my solution as an answer below which might helpful for others too..

Comment: Yours helped me solve the problem @ManirajMurugan :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" (change)="checkValue(isChecked)" />
```

inside your  class:

```
checkValue(event: any){
   console.log(event);

if(any){
// disable value
}else{
//enable value
}
}
```

Hope you get the logic.